# How can I fix CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, core-graphics

This is the code that I am working with:

```
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height);

    CGRect newRect = imageRect;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, oldImage.scale);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -(newRect.size.height));
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextClipToMask(ctx, newRect, oldImage.CGImage);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, newRect);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    CGContextClipToMask(ctx, imageRect, oldImage.CGImage);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, tintColor.CGColor);

    CGContextFillRect(ctx, imageRect);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I continue to get errors in the console, I'm not sure what to try or what is not being done correctly.

Comment: This error comes when your image width and height would be zero.

Answer (score 0):

The exact cause of above error :- Since the current context size is zero so you are adding **clip** to current Context  which do not exist in real sense . So above error occurs frequently .

**So check oldImage do exist or not in above function .**

so Updated code looks like :

```
    if ( oldImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oldImage.png"]) {

        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height);
        CGRect newRect = imageRect;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, oldImage.scale);
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -(newRect.size.height));
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
        CGContextClipToMask(ctx, newRect, oldImage.CGImage);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0].CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, newRect);
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
        CGContextClipToMask(ctx, imageRect, oldImage.CGImage);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, tintColor.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, imageRect);
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
     }
     else {
     //image do not exist
     // Unable to change into New Image
}
```